# Where can I download the Mist browser? (NOT the Ethereum wallet)

Tags: mist

I want to download the Mist browser (as opposed to the Ethereum Wallet accessible via ethereum.org) but can't find a link.

The Github repo (https://github.com/ethereum/mist) and latest release page has a link for the Ethereum Wallet but not for the full Mist browser as far as I can see.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is planned to be released at a later time, however for testing purposes, a developer release was made in November: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.3.6

It is not compatible with Homestead, well at least the included `geth`/`eth` certainly isn't.

Comment: Is the mist browser (not wallet) under developement at the moment? I can not find news or anything from the near past. Is there a website where I can periodically check for updates?

Comment: @Ba5t14n you can star this project on Github, or head there for info.  https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/

Answer (score 4):

You can now download Mist as a standalone application from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

---

Old answer:

The two are actually the same application currently, but Mist is under heavy development. You can run the Ethereum Wallet in Mist mode, just start the Wallet binary with `--mode mist`.

You can find the latest version [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

For example on Mac, run `/Applications/Ethereum-Wallet.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --mode mist` in Terminal.

Comment: I almost asked a question for this.. thanks! Too bad this isn't easier, it would help thedao voting rates..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Reddit thread that suggests building it from source is the best way to get an up-to-date Mist:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4kmoxi/why_is_the_mist_browser_functionality_hidden_why/

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. Mist the *Wallet* and Mist the *Browser*. Basically the wallet will evolve into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The dapp browsing capability is not integrated into mist right now.  It is supposed to come in a future release.

Comment: It is in the 0.3.6 release.

Answer (score 0):

All the mist releases are available in github under 
:https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/